# Fully functional JTree within a JTable's cell not functional

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtree

I'm trying to get a JTree which will update a data model into a cell of a table. Using the existing sample code, I can create a tree that will pass its check box state to another object and save it (which the swing example didn't do). I have a JTable which will render a JTree, however once the tree is in the table's cell it no longer responds to user input. I have tried adding a mouse listener to the table, and using dispatchEvent, but that didn't seem to do anything.

tree embedded into cell

[Table Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOcBF.png)

Just the tree

[Tree Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgEgd.png)

Here is the source:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellEditor;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class CheckBoxNodeTreeSample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CheckBox Tree");

        CheckBoxNode accessibilityOptions[] = {
            new CheckBoxNode(
            "Move system caret with focus/selection changes", false),
            new CheckBoxNode("Always expand alt text for images", true)};
        CheckBoxNode browsingOptions[] = {
            new CheckBoxNode("Notify when downloads complete", true),
            new CheckBoxNode("Disable script debugging", true),
            new CheckBoxNode("Use AutoComplete", true),
            new CheckBoxNode("Browse in a new process", false)};
        Vector accessVector = new NamedVector("Accessibility",
                accessibilityOptions);
        Vector browseVector = new NamedVector("Browsing", browsingOptions);
        Object rootNodes[] = {accessVector, browseVector};
        Vector rootVector = new NamedVector("Root", rootNodes);
        JTree tree = new JTree(rootVector);

        CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();
        tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        tree.setCellEditor(new CheckBoxNodeEditor(tree));
        tree.setEditable(true);
        tree.setRootVisible(true);


        String[] headers = {"this",
            "mixed"};
        Object[][] data = {{"the", tree}, {"other", "ifasdfasd"}};

        JTable table = new JTable(data, headers) {

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int i, int i1) {
                return false;
            }

        };
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jtable, Object o, boolean bln, boolean bln1, int i, int i1) {
                if (o instanceof JTree) {
                    jtable.setRowHeight(((JTree) o).getPreferredSize().height + 20);
                    return ((JTree) o);
                }
                return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(jtable, o, bln, bln1, i, i1);
            }
        });

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class CheckBoxNodeRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {

    private JCheckBox leafRenderer = new JCheckBox();

    private DefaultTreeCellRenderer nonLeafRenderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();

    Color selectionBorderColor, selectionForeground, selectionBackground,
            textForeground, textBackground;

    protected JCheckBox getLeafRenderer() {
        return leafRenderer;
    }

    public CheckBoxNodeRenderer() {
        Font fontValue;
        fontValue = UIManager.getFont("Tree.font");
        if (fontValue != null) {
            leafRenderer.setFont(fontValue);
        }
        Boolean booleanValue = (Boolean) UIManager
                .get("Tree.drawsFocusBorderAroundIcon");
        leafRenderer.setFocusPainted((booleanValue != null)
                && (booleanValue.booleanValue()));

        selectionBorderColor = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBorderColor");
        selectionForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionForeground");
        selectionBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBackground");
        textForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textForeground");
        textBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textBackground");
    }

    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
            boolean hasFocus) {

        Component returnValue;
        if (leaf) {

            String stringValue = tree.convertValueToText(value, selected,
                    expanded, leaf, row, false);
            leafRenderer.setText(stringValue);
            leafRenderer.setSelected(false);

            leafRenderer.setEnabled(tree.isEnabled());

            if (selected) {
                leafRenderer.setForeground(selectionForeground);
                leafRenderer.setBackground(selectionBackground);
            } else {
                leafRenderer.setForeground(textForeground);
                leafRenderer.setBackground(textBackground);
            }

            if ((value != null) && (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
                Object userObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value)
                        .getUserObject();
                if (userObject instanceof CheckBoxNode) {
                    CheckBoxNode node = (CheckBoxNode) userObject;
                    leafRenderer.setText(node.getText());
                    leafRenderer.setSelected(node.isSelected());
                }
            }
            returnValue = leafRenderer;
        } else {
            returnValue = nonLeafRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree,
                    value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}

class CheckBoxNodeEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TreeCellEditor {

    CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();

    ChangeEvent changeEvent = null;

    JTree tree;
    CheckBoxNode checkBoxNode;

    public CheckBoxNodeEditor(JTree tree) {
        this.tree = tree;

    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        JCheckBox cb = renderer.getLeafRenderer();
        CheckBoxNode node = new CheckBoxNode(checkBoxNode.text, cb.isSelected());
        return node;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject event) {
        boolean returnValue = false;
        if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
            MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;
            TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(mouseEvent.getX(),
                    mouseEvent.getY());
            if (path != null) {
                Object node = path.getLastPathComponent();
                if ((node != null) && (node instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node;
                    Object userObject = treeNode.getUserObject();
                    returnValue = ((treeNode.isLeaf()) && (userObject instanceof CheckBoxNode));
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {

        if (((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject() instanceof CheckBoxNode) {
            checkBoxNode = (CheckBoxNode) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
        }

        Component editor = renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
                true, expanded, leaf, row, true);

        // editor always selected / focused
        ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
                if (stopCellEditing()) {
                    fireEditingStopped();
                }
            }
        };
        if (editor instanceof JCheckBox) {
            ((JCheckBox) editor).addItemListener(itemListener);
        }
        System.out.println(checkBoxNode);
        return editor;
    }
}

class CheckBoxNode {

    String text;

    boolean selected;

    public CheckBoxNode(String text, boolean selected) {
        this.text = text;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean newValue) {
        selected = newValue;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String newValue) {
        text = newValue;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "[" + text + "/" + selected + "]";
    }
}

class NamedVector extends Vector {

    String name;

    public NamedVector(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public NamedVector(String name, Object elements[]) {
        this.name = name;
        for (int i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++) {
            add(elements[i]);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "[" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: `JTable.setDefaultCellEditor` seems to be missing. BTW using a JTree as cell value is a bit overdone, maybe a TreeModel would be nicer as value.

Comment: I tried adding a cell editor, however I could not get anything to work.

Comment: Maybe make a small proof-of-concept program first. Otherwise go for simplicity if you can and do not use a JTable.

Comment: This was the POC... I was able to get it working on the bigger project, however whenever the JTree cells are visible it causes my other background UI components from repainting. As soon as you scroll the trees out of view, the background repaints....

Answer (score 1):

This code took care of it, and behaves well:

```
class JTreeCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
        implements TableCellEditor {
    Object obj;



    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return obj; //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable jtable, Object o, boolean bln, int i, int i1) {
       obj = o;
        if (o instanceof JTree) {
            JTree tree = (JTree) o;

            tree.addTreeExpansionListener(new TreeExpansionListener() {

                @Override
                public void treeExpanded(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
                    jtable.setRowHeight(tree.getPreferredSize().height);
                }

                @Override
                public void treeCollapsed(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
                    jtable.setRowHeight(tree.getPreferredSize().height);
                }
            });
        }
        JTreeTableCellRenderer renderer = new JTreeTableCellRenderer();
        return renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(jtable, o, bln, bln, i, i1);

    }
}

class JTreeTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    Object obj;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jtable, Object o, boolean bln, boolean bln1, int i, int i1) {
        if (o instanceof JTree) {
            JTree tree = (JTree) o;
            jtable.setRowHeight(tree.getPreferredSize().height);
            tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {

                @Override
                public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                    jtable.setRowHeight(tree.getPreferredSize().height);
                }
            });
            return tree;
        }
        obj = o;
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(jtable, o, bln, bln1, i, i1);
    }
}
```